# How to make composer use php72 instead of php

Tags: php, php-7

How to make composer use php72 instead of php

I have two commands in my linux:

`php` and `php72`

so when I use something like:

```
composer install somepackage
```

it says that my php is 5.6 and the installation package requires php7, but how can I make it use the `php72` to install the package?

Comment: What is the output of `php -v`

Comment: Symlinking, changing composer so it uses `php72` instead of `php`, run `php72 path/to/composer.phar update`, change that `php` points to `php72`.. quite a few ways.